# Set Column Value Using Multiple Dataframes and in a Specified Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

I have two datasets, one tracks the daily status of rental unit (5 Columns: DATE_KEY, PRODUCT_KEY, FISCAL_YR, RENTAL_NM, OCCUPIED_IND). This table has an entry for every day from 01-SEP-19 to 21-DEC-22. The rental can be set to active or inactive and can only be occupied if active. I need to build a 6th column (ACTIVE_IND) to show the active status of the rental. The second dataset, ACTIVE_AUDIT_DF, shows when the status was changed but I cannot figure out how to set the dates and the active status correctly in the RENTAL_DF.

RENTAL_DF

| DATE_KEY | PRODUCT_KEY | FISCAL_YR | RENTAL_NM | OCCUPIED_IND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20190901 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| 20190902 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| 20190903 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20221218 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| 20221219 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| 20221220 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |
| 20221221 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 |

ACTIVE_AUDIT_DF

| DATE_KEY | ACTION | ACTIVE_IND | RENTAL_NM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200523 | Active: N -> Y | 1 | Blanco2Room |
| 20210322 | Active: Y -> N | 0 | Blanco2Room |

I am looking for a way to combine the data so I get an output that looks like the final table below.

FINAL_DF

| DATE_KEY | PRODUCT_KEY | FISCAL_YR | RENTAL_NM | OCCUPIED_IND | ACTIVE_IND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20190901 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20200522 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 0 |
| 20200523 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 1 | 1 |
| 20200524 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20210321 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 1 | 1 |
| 20210322 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 0 |
| 20210323 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 20221221 | 135 | FY20 | Blanco2Room | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Left merge the two dataframes on `['DATE_KEY', 'RENTAL_NM']` then `groupby` on `RENTAL_NM` and forward fill the values in `ACTIVE_IND`

```
RENTAL_DF['ACTIVE_IND'] = (
    RENTAL_DF
    .merge(ACTIVE_AUDIT_DF, on=['DATE_KEY', 'RENTAL_NM'], how='left')
    .groupby('RENTAL_NM')['ACTIVE_IND'].ffill()
)
```